# How do I change the rear tire on old Raleigh "Tourist" 3-speed

Tags: tire, wheels

Never changed the rear tire on this bike. How and what is loosened to remove the rear wheel so the tire can be changed?

Comment: It's complicated.  You generally need to disconnect the gear-shifting cable by somehow unscrewing it from the hub, but the details vary.

Comment: Do you need to change the tyre, or fix a puncture?  With some faffery, its possible to patch a puncture without removing the wheel from the bike.

Comment: Assuming it's an old Sturmey Archer hub (since you said it's an old Raleigh bike) this video shows how you break the gear change mechanism, and from there you can take the wheel off normally (unscrew the bolts). This is the same as described in @mikes answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvR0S6lHJ4Q

Answer (score 2):

This is where a 60 second Youtube  video is worth 1000 words. The adjustment takes less than a minute. There are a couple methods. If it is shifting ok now, mark the threaded rod where the cable attaches. Place the shifter in gear 3. Loosen the jam nut 1/4 turn, just enough to allow the cable end to unscrew from the threaded rod. with the cable disconnected, remove shifter chain guide nut. It may be separate or part of the axle nut. Remove the wheel as you would any other nutted axle. Reinstall the repaired wheel. You can reattach the cable screwing the cable end up to the jam nut. Tighten the jam nut. To check the adjustment. Place the shifter in 2nd gear. If you look at the shift chain guide you will notice two observation holes on the sides. If properly adjusted you should see about 1mm of the straight rod exposed. If more than 1mm is exposed loosen the jam nut on the cable end and expose a less of the threaded rod and tighten the jam nut. If less than 1mm is exposed loosen the jam nut and screw the cable end to expose less threaded rod.

Comment: There are many 3-speed systems with different adjustment methods. Some of them don't even have the shift chain.

Comment: @ojs Presumably old Raleigh bike means old Sturmey Archer hub, which this answer seems based on.